# Navigate to multiple urls from extension script and message passing to content script on each url

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

So here's my problem : I (try to) develop a web extension that :

- opens a panel with a button
- after clicking the button, a new tab is open in the browser
- on this new tab, from extension script I loop through an urls array and update the browser's new tab. On each url, I pass a message to content script to scrape a title under a "a" element on the page. After scraping, content script send the text title to extension script.

Here's my scripts :

Background script background.js :

```
    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
        var tabUrl = tab.url;
        originalWindowId = tab.windowId;
        var popupURL = chrome.runtime.getURL("extension/main_panel.html");
        chrome.windows.create({
            url: popupURL,
            type: 'panel',
            width: 600,
            height: 520
        }, function (window) {
            extensionWindowId = window.id;
        });
    });
```

Main panel main_panel.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="../background/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="title" id="main_title">
        <p>EXTRACTIFY</p>
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="scrap_button">SCRAP</button>    
    <script src="functions/scrap.js"></script>
    <script src="functions/main_panel.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Main panel script (that retrieves the button from main_panel.html) main_panel.js :

```
var urls = ["https://forum.openstreetmap.fr/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6811&start=0", "https://forum.openstreetmap.fr/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6811&start=25"];
var scrapButton = document.getElementById("scrap_button");
scrapButton.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    chrome.tabs.create({
        url: "about:newtab"
    }, function (newTab) {
        var newTabId = newTab.id;
        console.log("created newTab : " + newTabId);
        for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
            chrome.tabs.update(newTabId, {
                url: urls[i]
            });
            chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (newTabId , info) {
              if (info.status === 'complete') {
                var port = chrome.tabs.connect(newTabId, {
                    name: "scrap"
                });
                port.postMessage({
                    type: "title"
                });
                port.onMessage.addListener(function (msg) {
                    console.log("recieved message : " + msg.title);
                });
              }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Content script scrapContent.js :

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function (port) {
    console.assert(port.name == "scrap");
    port.onMessage.addListener(function (msg) {
        console.log("recieved message : " + msg.type); 
        if (msg.type == "title") {
            var title = $("h3.first a").text();
            port.postMessage({
                title: title
            });
        }
    });
});
```

What the script actually do : It successes to scrape the second url and transmit the information I want to extension script. But It falls to scrape the first page. So I suspect a problem of (-a)synchronization.

Many thanks for your help !

Comment: Yep, this is a standard problem with using asynchronous functions inside loops, which is solved by switching to Promises or async/await syntax (best with the [Mozilla's WebExtension polyfill](https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill)) and scoped `let` variables, see [Asynchronous Process inside a javascript for loop](//stackoverflow.com/q/11488014)

Comment: Woo so quick answer for a so long problem ;) ! Many thanks, I go there and return if questions !